# Protractor Testing not working

Tags: protractor

The question is related to protractor testing. I am testing an application using Protractor. I want to inspect one element but unable to get the solution. The HTML code for the element to be inspected is :

```
<span class="ng-binding"> Admitted(7)</span>
```

As in selenium we do
`element(by.class....)` is not possible here in protractor. So Can any one help me in this.

Comment: Why `element(by.class....)` is not possible?

Comment: I tried that too but its throwing an error as "By class is not a function.

Comment: Which is true. Post more code, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can also inspect in protractor as

```
element(by.css('span ng-binding'))
```

or

```
element(by.css('ng-binding'));
```

If there are more than one element with class name "ng-binding",
then use
`element.all(by.css('ng-binding'))` 
to inspect element.

Comment: None of your suggestions will work. Should be `element(by.css('span.ng-binding'))` or `element(by.css('.ng-binding'));`

Comment: while inspecting the element with the above mentioned code its throwing the error as "No Element found using locator By(css selector ,ng binding).